# Why isOperational() in mobile vision text Recognizer in a device return true and in other return false?

Tags: java, android, vision, text-recognition

### Why `isOperational()` in mobile vision text recognizer returns false?

At first, mobile vision only show preview camera and after many tries to get the result, I saw that the texts recognized but in one device it works and in other device does not.

What should I do?

For example, in one device, `isOperational()` returns `false`, and it goes to `readstate()` and after that goes to `looper()` and stays on it!

in other device it only return `false` and doesn't go to `looper`.

**I want ask other questions about it:**

1. My first question is: how does isOperational() work? I can't understand it.
2. Maybe it goes to looper to download the native library in a queue and after many try, at last download completes and work. Can it be correct? Or is it just a bug that it goes to looper? Anywhere, what should I do?
3. Can I work on this when it works in one device I tried and in other does not? Or it must work in every device to I can work on it? And I get `.apk` from project but it can't install in devices, why?
4. Should it check for network?
5. Should it check for access to the memory?

note: it works with camera API and its deprecated. maybe the problem is with this!

```
  TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build();
  textRecognizer.setProcessor(new OcrDetectorProcessor(graphicOverlay));

  if (!textRecognizer.**isOperational**()) {
       // Note: The first time that an app using a Vision API is installed on a
      // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
      // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
      // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any text,
      // barcodes, or faces.
      //
      // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
      // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
      // downloads complete on device.
        Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");

      // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
     // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.*
        IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
        boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;
         if (hasLowStorage) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
        }
    }

    *// Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
    // to other detection examples to enable the text recognizer to detect small pieces of text.*
    cameraSource =
            new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
            .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
            .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
            .setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO : null)
            .build();
}
```

It doesn't produce any error and show preview camera but doesn't recognize texts in some devices.

Comment: Hi again, if my explain is unclear, please tell me to explain more. I work on this question more than 2 weeks and read a lot of stackoverflow questions but can't find the problem to solve it.

Comment: libocr.so library load status: false                                         Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting. (it shows in Run tab) but the internet isn't slow and limiting.

Comment: I checked that google play service is update but it can't help to download vision library :-(